# Java AES: Generate Key using a single id as source

Tags: java, encryption, java-security

I need to generate a `Key` in order to use it for encryption and decryption using an AES cipher.

The key must be generated on runtime using a single `id` value.

How could I generate a `Key` taking a single string as source?

Comment: As a starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#SecretKeyFactory (although the examples themselves are a bit dated)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this can help you.

```
package com.lahiru.security;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESEncryptionDecryption {

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String id = "00001";
        String plainText = "This is plain text";

        String cipherText = encrypt(plainText, id);
        System.out.println("Cipher Text after encrption ::: " + cipherText);
        System.out.println("Plain Text after decryption ::: " + decrypt(cipherText, id));

    }


    public static void setKey(String myKey) 
    {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); 
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret) 
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) 
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just using a hash function (SHA-1) is not sufficient and even adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption.